# Math Rich Text Editor for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Looking for rich text editor that can take math symboles that I can easily integrate into my rails app.

Found http://www.wiris.com/ which did most things, just not written to support rails.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: The wiris solution you mention is just Javascript. Why do you think it "is not written to support rails" ???

Comment: Ah sorry wasn't specific, i need a rich text editor that also supports math, Wiris javascript only plugin is just for mathml. To plug it into a 3rd party text editor e.g. ckeditor you need a backend http://www.wiris.com/en/plugins/docs/ckeditor

Comment: you find any leads on this?

Comment: yup wiris is creating a rails port (soon not released yet) we are using the equation editor via codecogs, however it's that good.